# No output while using NSLog()

Tags: objective-c

I am now working on a music-App (exercise from the book I'm reading.)

This is the code I now have:

Song.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Song : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title, *artist, *album, *time; //creat the 4 instance variables for the song info

-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)theTitle andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andTime:(NSString *)theTime; //set all info with one method

-(void) list; //print the song info

@end
```

Song.m:

```
#import "Song.h"

@implementation Song

@synthesize title, artist, album, time;

-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)theTitle andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andTime:(NSString *)theTime {
    title = [NSString stringWithString:theTitle];
    artist = [NSString stringWithString:theArtist];
    album = [NSString stringWithString:theAlbum];
    time = [NSString stringWithString:theTime];
}

-(void) list {
    if (title != nil)
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
    if (artist != nil)
        NSLog(@"Artist: %@", artist);
    if (album != nil)
        NSLog(@"Album: %@", album);
    if (time != nil)
        NSLog(@"Time: %@", time);
}

@end
```

Playlist.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Song.h"

@interface Playlist : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *playlistName; //name of the playlist
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *playListOfSongs; //songs stored in mutable array

-(void) addSongToPlaylist:(Song *)song; //add song to playlist-array

-(id) initWithPlaylistName:(NSString *)name; //init playlist object and set name

-(void) list; //list all song information for the songs in the playlist-array. Here the list-method from the Song-class is used

@end
```

Playlist.m:

```
#import "Playlist.h"

@implementation Playlist

@synthesize playlistName, playListOfSongs;

-(void) addSongToPlaylist:(Song *)song {
    [playListOfSongs addObject:song];
}

-(id) initWithPlaylistName:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        playlistName = [NSString stringWithString:name];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) init {
    return [self initWithPlaylistName:@"Unknown Playlist"];
}

-(void) list {
    for (Song *nextSong in playListOfSongs) {
        [nextSong list];
    }
}

@end
```

MusicCollection.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Playlist.h"

@interface MusicCollection : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *collection; //playlists stored in an array

-(void) addPlaylistToCollection:(Playlist *)playlist; //add playlist to collection-array

@end
```

Musiccollection.m:

```
#import "MusicCollection.h"

@implementation MusicCollection

@synthesize collection;

-(void) addPlaylistToCollection:(Playlist *)playlist {
    [collection addObject:playlist];
}

@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "song.h"
#import "Playlist.h"
#import "MusicCollection.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Song *song1, *song2, *song3, *song4, *song5;
        Playlist *playlist1, *playlist2;
        MusicCollection *collection;

        [song1 setTitle:@"Teenage Dream" andArtist:@"Katy Perry" andAlbum:@"The Complete Confection" andTime:@"3:48"];
        [song2 setTitle:@"Forever And Always" andArtist:@"Taylor Swift" andAlbum:nil andTime:nil];
        [song3 setTitle:@"Firework" andArtist:song1.artist andAlbum:song1.album andTime:nil];
        [song4 setTitle:@"Stay Stay Stay" andArtist:song2.artist andAlbum:@"Red" andTime:nil];
        [song5 setTitle:@"22" andArtist:song2.artist andAlbum:song4.album andTime:nil];

        [playlist1 addSongToPlaylist:song1];
        [playlist1 addSongToPlaylist:song3];

        [playlist2 addSongToPlaylist:song1];
        [playlist2 addSongToPlaylist:song2];
        [playlist2 addSongToPlaylist:song5];

        [collection addPlaylistToCollection:playlist1];
        [collection addPlaylistToCollection:playlist2];

        [song1 list];

        [playlist2 list];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the Song class I have declared and defined a list method, which uses NSLog().

In main.m I used the print method, but I have no output on my Xcode windows.

I also added a list method in the Playlist class, which uses the list method from the Song class.

Even that isn't working.

Is here anyone who could explain to me why I don't get any output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your Song objects are nil.  Calling a method of a nil object will have no effect.  You need to alloc and init each of them before use.

```
song1 = [[Song alloc] init];
song2 = [[Song alloc] init];
... etc...
```

Comment: Oh, that's really dumb of me. ;-) But now I have allocated and initialized everything, it still gives no output...

Comment: Nevermind, I replaced all the song info that was set nil to @"Unknown", and now it gives output. Strange, since a NSString could be nil...

Comment: @bbamhart Now I get output when I use the 'list' method directly on a song object, but when I use the 'list' method from Playlist, like '[playlist2 list];' I get no output. The list method from Playlist uses the list method from Song, so it should work...      PS: How do I put code in comments?

Comment: Does your app crash when running?  song2 album is nil which will cause `[NSString stringWithString:album]` to crash.

Comment: Just use `album = theAlbum` in Song when setting the detail information and not stringWithString.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta do

```
-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)theTitle andArtist:(NSString *)theArtist andAlbum:(NSString *)theAlbum andTime:(NSString *)theTime {
    self.title = theTitle;
    self.artist = theArtist;
    self.album = theAlbum;
    self.time = theTime;
}

-(void) list {
    if (title != nil)
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", self.title);
    if (artist != nil)
        NSLog(@"Artist: %@", self.artist);
    if (album != nil)
        NSLog(@"Album: %@", self.album);
    if (time != nil)
        NSLog(@"Time: %@", self.time);
}
```

There is absolutely no reason to use the `stringWithString` method in your case either.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that. I saw it in an example in the book, and thought it was better to use 'stringWithString:'.